# What is the purpose of RegisterGlobalFilters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, filter

In MVC3, I have CustomErrors enabled this way:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/Generic"/>
```

And It works whatever I add or not the `HandleErrorAttribute` to the `GlobalFilterCollection` filters.

In `void Application_Start()`, it does not change anything if I comment out this line
`RegisterGlobalFilters (GlobalFilters.Filters);`

What is the real purpose of this call to `RegisterGlobalFilters`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working because you still have a defaultRedirect specified.

If you remove it, your custom errors will not work if you have `customErrors="On"` and do not have either `HandleError specified OR if you comment out:

```
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

So in short - you do need to register your global filters if you want this to work and have the error details properly pushed through, otherwise I don't think your `HandleErrorInfo` values will be accessible in `/Error/Generic`.