# What is the purpose of FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters) inside Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have read the similar question[What is the purpose of RegisterGlobalFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343946/what-is-the-purpose-of-registerglobalfilters)

but unable to get the answer, the question somewhat revolves around some other stuff too and the anwser doesn't seems fullfilling to me.

My question is:-
what is the purpose of this line inside global.asax in MVC 5 `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);`

1. Why it is needed ?
2. What is the purpose of adding/registering
   filters?
3. What does the filter have to do?

Comment: This question is too general for StackOverflow.  Try a search engine first.  https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+globalfilters

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `FilterConfig` is a custom class in your code, normally under the App_Start folder and generally looks somewhat like this:

```
public class FilterConfig {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

You can add custom filters to this list that should be executed on each request. If you inherit from the [`FilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.aspx) class or one of its [inheritors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#inheritanceContinued) you can create your own filters, for instance a log filter.

You can also apply these filters to controllers that requires certain constraints. For instance, if you add the [`[RequireHttps]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute.aspx) filter attribute (example below) to a controller or a method in your controller, the user must use a https request in order to execute the code in the method. So instead of handling it in each method, the filter takes care of it.

```
[RequireHttps]
public class MyController : ApiController {
    // only https requests will get through to this method.
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
       return Ok();
    }
}
```

You can think of it as a little box that sits between the users browser and your controller and *filters* out any invalid requests, or one the executes when a controller is done and you need to postprocess the result to the user.

If you want to read more, msdn has more details regarding filters at [Filtering in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28VS.98%29.aspx).

Comment: Also, for the purpose of `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute())`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17917434/770230

Comment: This is what I like **You can think of it as a little box that sits between the users browser and your controller and filters out any invalid requests, or one the executes when a controller is done and you need to postprocess the result to the user.**

Comment: Note that it is MVC controller specific, and not used for WebAPI